# Количество дней в этом месяце

Tags: c++

Составить программу, которая в зависимости от порядкового номера месяца (1,2,…,12) выводит на экран количество дней в этом месяце. Год может быть високосным (информация об этом вводится с клавиатуры).

Comment: Какие идеи?

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы найти мальчика, который напишет программу. Можно начать искать среди одноклассников, тренеруя коммуникативные способности в реале.

Comment: Бедная девушка. А ей, наверное, так на дискотеку хочется. А тут - С++. ((((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать массив, содержащий количество дней в месяце.

```
int days_1[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int days_2[] = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
// далее просто берете значение из нужного массива для нужного месяца.
// days_1[7] - количество дней в 8-м месяце, т.е. в августе.
```

Comment: Для @Anuta может и подойдет, но вообще нет особого смысла создавать два массива, различающихся всего 1 элементом.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос на самом деле довольно интересный.
Выбраны лучшие решения из статьи на хабре:  http://habrahabr.ru/post/261773/

---

Способ 1. Когда каждый байт на счету (без високосности)

```
days = 28 + ((0x3bbeecc >> (month * 2)) & 3);
```

---

Способ 2. Просто и наглядно (без високосности)

```
function getDays(m){
 return m === 2 ? 28 : 30 + (m > 7 ? m+1 : m) % 2;
}
```

---

Способ 3. Самый очевидный (без високосности)

```
[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month — 1]
```

---

Способ 4. Интерполяция Лагранжа (без високосности)

```
function d(x){
    return ((16*Math.pow(x,11) + 12*Math.pow(x,10) + 4*Math.pow(x,8) + 21*Math.pow(x,7) + 29*Math.pow(x,6) + 10*Math.pow(x,5) + 12*Math.pow(x,4) + 34*Math.pow(x,3) + 26*Math.pow(x,2) + 5*x + 10) % 37);
}
```

---

Способ 5. Исключительно простыми операциями (без високосности)

```
function f(x) { return 28 + (x + Math.floor(x/8)) % 2 + 2 % x + 2 * Math.floor(1/x); }
```

---

Способ 6. Исключительно простыми операциями с високосностью

```
function f(x,y) { return 28 + (x + Math.floor(x / 8)) % 2 + 2 % x + Math.floor((2 - ((y % 4) * ((y % 100) + (y % 400)) + 2) % ((y % 4) * ((y % 100) + (y % 400)) + 1)) / x) + Math.floor(1/x) - Math.floor((1 - ((y % 4) * ((y % 100) + (y % 400)) + 2) % ((y % 4) * ((y % 100) + (y % 400)) + 1))/x); }
```

Answer (score -1):

> > ```
> > #include <iostream>
> > #include <cstdlib>  
> > using namespace std; 
> > int main() {
> > setlocale(0, "");
> > int q = 28, w = 30, e = 31,a;
> > cout << "Введите номер месяца:";
> > cin >> a;
> > if (a < 1){ cout << "Ошибка ввода месяца" << endl; }
> > if (a < 2){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << e << endl; }
> > else if (a < 3){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << q << endl; }
> > else if (a < 4){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << e << endl; }
> > else if (a < 5){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << w << endl; }
> > else if (a < 6){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << e << endl; }
> > else if (a < 7){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << w << endl; }
> > else if (a < 8){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << e << endl; }
> > else if (a < 9){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << e << endl; }
> > else if (a < 10){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << w << endl; }
> > else if (a < 11){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << e << endl; }
> > else if (a < 12){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << w << endl; }
> > else if (a < 13){ cout << "Количество дней в месяце: " << e << endl; }
> > else if (a > 12){ cout << "Ошибка ввода месяца" << endl; }
> > system("pause");
> > return 0;
> > ```
> >
> > }